# Is 2.4Ghz or 5Ghz better for use in a Wifi network in a stone house?

Tags: wireless-networking

The MiFi device I'm setting up for use in a granite farmhouse on vacation supports 2.4GHz *or* 5GHz but not both at the same time.

I know 2.4GHz can interfere with bluetooth but in this building, getting reception across the building is a greater issue. Which frequency should find my walls least opaque?

Comment: I have had problems in stone buildings, though I haven't lived in one since the advent of wireless communications. I run both networks in my brick house, and 2.4GHz has much better coverage and I use it almost exclusively. In your environment I would recommend a couple of repeaters, preferably using power-line networking as the signal source.

Answer (score 0):

Generaly speaking:

2.4Ghz has greater [penetrating] range and if getting reception across the building is the most important then use 2.4GHz.

5Ghz has greater speed. Use this for access points if you sit next to the device.

Disclaimer: Reflections against walls etc can make quite a difference per building. The only real test is it try both at your destination. I strongly suspect that the 2.4GHz one will work best, but there are always exceptions.